# Connecting to MySQL through WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I had paid VPS for 1 month and everything i created i've tested it on the VPS. But now i want to make that on my WAMP, so i have installed WAMP.

My tables on the site depends from my mysql base, but they are not shown because there is some error with connecting to MySQL.

MySQL connection php file:

```
<?php  
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
?>
```

Is there something that i need to change in the wamp settings to enable connection ?

Comment: Check if MySQL is runnign.

Comment: @Todor I think its running because phpmyadmin is working

Comment: phpmyadmin is on your local machine or on the VPS ?

Comment: My VPS isn't working anymore so its on my local pc

Comment: I can see you still dont have an answer, so i go with my next question. Can you connect to mysql via console. How to test id -> start cmd.exe, navigate to the location where mysql.exe is, usually its in (C:\Program Files /(x86)/\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.X/bin/) and then write down into the console: mysql -uroot;

Answer (score 0):

Try this order

```
<?php
    $hostname = "localhost"; 
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    //connection to the database

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
?>
```

Sometimes, you should follow the order of dbhandle values.

Comment: Same... Where can i see this messages like ("Connected to MySQL<br>") and ("Unable to connect to MySQL"). I've searched in WAMP/logs but there aren't any errors or messages.

Comment: I think password is wrong. try to change it! and try to connect into phpMyAdmin dashboard via WAMP `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`